# wxFrame not closing

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a frame which I use as the main form (mainFrame), it inherits from mainFrameBase, which inherits from wxFrame.

It has a "close" system button. When it is pressed the app shuts down. All very much to my liking.

I inherit another frame from mainFrameBase (progScreen). When a button is pressed, the progScreen is shown. When I click its system close button, the form does not close.

What I want to achieve with this setup is that you can click a button on the main frame and a slightly different view of the main frame is shown to allow the user to "progam" certain buttons.

By the way, I'm using [WXFormBuilder](http://wxformbuilder.org/) (excellent program) to create the screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is create two panels with the controls you want, one for the regular screen and one for the programming screen. Then when you want to switch, you hide one panel and show the other. That way, both screens are contained in one frame that when closed, exits the program. I actually have a tutorial that is similar to this here:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/16/wxpython-how-to-switch-between-panels/

Hope that helps!

Comment: I do that for other things but what I wanted to achieve is reusability. I have this screen layed out, why reinvent the weel.

Comment: What do you mean by that? If you put the panels into their own classes, you can reuse them in any frame or dialog you want.

Comment: Aha like that you mean. Maybe that s a good idea. The end result sorta be the same. I'll try it. Thanks

Comment: What I ended up doing was to create create the panels as suggested and then at runtime add them to the main form. When a certain button is pressed I open a dialog and add the panels there as well. Some pieces of code I moved to helper functions in a separate script. I can now reuse a lot of code! Thanks for the suggestion